# Wordpress Custom Post Type Popup—jquery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, popup, custom-post-type

I'm trying to use jquery (bpopup)to load a custom post type post into a popup window. An example of what I'm trying to do is at http://outpost.la —just click on any of the images to see the popup.

I think I ultimately need to write a function to do this, but I'm not sure about how to do that. So far I just have two snippets of code—"button that triggers popup" and "element to pop up"—in my page template. The first snippet is doing what I want: displaying the series of custom post type titles as buttons. But the second snippet which is supposed to display the custom post type content in the popup is showing the titles + content of *all* of the custom post types.

Screenshot of the Popup w/ buttons in the background: 
http://cl.ly/image/1f0G0c2s2J3U

Code: 
`

```
<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->

<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio_project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$i = 0;

echo'<button class="my-button">';

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    if ($i % 0 == 0 && $i > 0) {
        echo '</button>' . "\n" . '<button class="my-button">';
    };
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php

$i++;

endwhile;

echo '</button>';
?>


<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">

<?php 
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

      <!-- pagination here -->

      <!-- the loop -->
      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <!-- end of the loop -->

      <!-- pagination here -->

      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else:  ?>
      <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
                                            <!-- end custom post type loop -->  

    </div>
     <!-- END Element to pop up -->

<script>
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery
;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            appendTo: 'body'
            , position: ['auto','0']
            , positionStyle: 'fixed'
            , scrollBar: 'false'

        });

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 4):

Actually `Wordpress` uses a different approach for `ajax` request. You have to understand that first. So, the simple prototype is something like this

```
// In your functions.php file
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ MyAjaxAction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ MyAjaxAction', 'MyAjaxFunction' ); 
function MyAjaxFunction() {
    // do query for your posts
    // process it
    // echo it
    die();
}
```

In your client side/jQuery code

```
$(function(){
    $('.myButton').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // other code
        $.ajax({
            'url':'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // admin-ajax.php will handle the request
            'type':'post',
            'data': {
                // this is the action hook to call the handler "MyAjaxFunction"
                'action': 'MyAjaxAction',
                // pass some data to post variblr to use in php/wordpress (optional)
                'id':'someId' // you can retrieve this using $_POST['id'];
            },
            'success':function(data){
                // returned data by wordpress
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the proper way to handle `ajax` request in `WordPress`, read [this article](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) for more help and as a bonus download [this book](http://wpajax.s3.amazonaws.com/2ndedition/wp-ajax-book.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJHNMGJCAUGWHDBMQ&Expires=1381526491&Signature=LOrnVw9gM52RVykznPms3vla42I=).